# What is the meaning of each sentence?

Tags: meaning

> 1. "Today is Sunday and I don't feel well because I have been drinking three days in a row: Thursday, Friday and Saturday."
> 2. "Today is Sunday and I'm not feeling well because I drank three days in a row: Thursday, Friday and Saturday."

What is the difference in meaning between these sentences? "Don't feel" seems to be more general.

And would it be possible to write:

"Today is Sunday and I'm not feeling well because I have drunk  three days in a row: Thursday, Friday and Saturday."

or

"Today is Sunday and I don't feel well because I have  drunk three days in a row: Thursday, Friday and Saturday."?

I think the present perfect tense can be used in this case because the action recently stopped.

Answer (score 1):

**"I don't feel well"** and **"I am not feeling well"** is showing the *same* meaning here.

**I have been drinking three days in a row** shows that he *still* might be drinking (hence the continuous tense)

**I drank three days in a row** means that he had drunk the drinks in the past, and is not drinking today.

Comment: Can we use present perfect simple in this example  to emphasize that the activity is finished and i think that 3 days in a row show the continuity of the action so no need to emphasize it

Comment: The simple perfect tense doesn't seem fitting to me, can't really point out why